# android studio generate signed apk problem ( Could not find kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar )

Tags: java, android-studio

when i want to generate signed apk (release version not debug version) in android studio, lead to this error :

**Could not find kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.0.1/kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar**

build project and run has no error but generate signed apk show top error

i had that problem in android studio version 3.6 and i updated to version 4.0.1 and gradle is 6.1.1
but nothing changed and i still have that error

i also create empty new project and add no more code but when generate signed apk that error exist .. i don't use kotlin in my code

my gradle content :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.0.1/kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar is a valid link and points to the correct JAR. Are you maybe behind a proxy that is interfering?

Comment: have u solved it ? am facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need use proxy or vpn to solve this problem .or can change :

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
```

to

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
```

and use gradle plugin version 6.5